# How to find range of Score using Linq query ( without maximum Score)

Tags: c#, linq

i have a table Grade level with

```
>Id  Grade Name MinScore
 1    A           90
 2    B           70
 3    C           60
 4    D           50
```

how to find a Grade with a Mark 65/62 as' C 'using linq query ( i dont have a field maximum Score )

Comment: not getting this: with a Mark 65/62 as' C. Please elaborate if you can

Comment: @TejasVaishnav: I believe these are score thresholds. 90 or above is an A, 70 to 89 is a B, 60 to 69 is a C, 50 to 59 is a D. Not sure what happens it if it below 50...

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way to achieve this would be this:

```
var mark = 65;
//'grades' represents the table
var letter = grades.Where(x => mark > x.MinScore).Min(x => x.GradeName);
```

- `.Where()`: First filter only the items where the mark is higher than the minimum score
- `.Min()`: Then take the lowest GradeName of the remaining items

### Edit:

Should the naming of the grade change, instead of A, B, C, ... and you can't rely on the alphabetical order anymore, then this one helps you out:

```
var mark = grades.Where(x => mark > x.MinScore)
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.MinScore)
                 .FirstOrDefault()?.GradeName;
```

- `.Where()`: First filter only the items where the mark is higher than the minimum score
- `.OrderByDescending()`: Order the items from high to low
- `.FirstOrDefault()`: Take the first item from the result
- Get the `GradeName` property

Notice the `?` in that line of code, that is a [**Null-conditional Operator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators).

Comment: The second bit of code also has the advantage that it deals better with scores less than 50.